# Camera problems after upgrade

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, webcam

After today's upgrade of 12.04 to the latest Linux kernel and Chrome to version 20 my camera (Creative Live! Cam Sicialize HD) behaves weirdly when I'm on Gmail page in Chrome: it blinks and the browser itself hangs from time to time for a few seconds. I don't know which affects which (i.e. Linux update troubles Chrome or vise versa) and so far could't find a solution.
It's obvious though that the above behavior is caused by Chrome's Talk plugin - when I close the Gmail tab the browser returns back to normal. 
Any ideas what it is and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the google talk plugin is flash based. You may be having problems with the new version of flash.

This isn't guaranteed to fix your problem, but try disabling the latest version of flash (will default to 11.2 instead).

- Type `about:plugins` in the url bar
- Click details
- Disable Flash

Comment: AFAIK Chrome 20 comes without Flash. shouldn't its plugin follow the suite? reason I'm asking is I just tried to re-install Chrome, and it manifested same ugly behavior - camera's LED blinking on Gmail page, browser freezing, so I ditched it again.
will try tomorrow. thanks...

Comment: In some cases in Ubuntu you will have to install Flash from the Software Center, even in Chrome.